# Requesting transaction with SOOMLA Android Store billing wrapper

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I'm trying to setup in-app billing for my Android game. Google Play is not making it easy (sigh). I came across a few open source libraries and it seems like [The SOOMLA Project](https://github.com/soomla/android-store) is the one more suited for games.

Their readme file explains how to change the android manifest and everything but it doesn't indicate how to request the transaction. Does anyone have experience with this library and can help me get started?

Comment: Funny - I think they just fixed their readme file because of me. Stack Overflow is such a great tool :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my question made them edit their readme file so the answer is:

```
StoreController.buyCurrencyPack(TEN_COINS_PACK.getProductId());
```

You have to define it first according to their documentation.

```
VirtualCurrencyPack TEN_COINS_PACK = new VirtualCurrencyPack(
        "10 Coins",            // name
        "A pack of 10 coins",  // description
        "themes/awsomegame/img/coins/10_coins.png", // image file path
        "10_coins",            // item id
        TEN_COINS_PACK_PRODUCT_ID, // product id in Google Market
        1.99,                  // actual price in $$
        10,                    // number of currencies in the pack
        COIN_CURRENCY,
        CURRENCYPACKS_CATEGORY);
```

https://github.com/soomla/android-store#in-app-purchasing